# PostgreSQL: double to bit conversion

Tags: postgresql, bit-manipulation

I need `bit(64)` representation of current epoch (the operations I need should be much easier in bits), so

```
SELECT extract('epoch' from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::bit(64)
```

But this gives me

```
ERROR: cannot cast type double precision to bit
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPD: In fact, I understood I should do it the other way, but the `ERROR` itself is still very strange for me.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of operation you have in mind? I can't think of anything that could be done with a timestamp that would be easier with a bit representation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just produce the key for table pagination. First bits are about time and the rest is my own ID. But it seems ok to just use INT instead of truncated DOUBLE as first 32 bits.

Comment: The answer can be found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263986/is-it-possible-to-get-the-binary-or-hexadecimal-representation-of-a-value-stor).